# Which field have I use to index

Tags: sql, indexing

When I create a table, I define a column as identity field and makes it as primary key.

But I want to know that have I index my rows on others fields such as text or numeric fields.

And is there any important tip to know that which field is better to index table on it?

Comment: The general explanation of indexes is too broad for Stack Overflow.  If you have a particular table or tables and queries that you want to optimize, then ask another question with detail about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use columns, that You'll use for selecting, sorting, filtering. Most databases use indexes to arrange records in trees, so when using ORDER BY xxx it'll be better to have index on xxx.

But keep in mind not to create too many indexes - they take space and grow quickly!